# Prolog Operator Priority Clash on multiple Ifs

Tags: prolog

I'm kind of new to prolog and can't figure out what's wrong with this.

```
ecoZona(Z):-
zona(Z, L1),
(L1 = [] -> 
    write('Zona nao encontrada'), nl,nl ;
    write('cenas\n'),
    listaEcos(L1,A,B,C,D),
    format('Ha ~w de Lixo Organico\n ~w de Papel\n ~w de Metal\n ~w de Vidro', [A, B, C, D]),
    max([A, B, C, D], X),
    F is div(700,X),
    M is mod(700,X),
    ( M <0 -> F is F+1; F is F+0),
    format('Sao Precisos ~w camioes', [F])).


listaEcos([],A,B,C,D).
listaEcos([L|R],A,B,C,D):-
findall([I,T,_,P], ecoponto(I, T, _, P), L2),
(L2 = [] ->
    write('---------\n');
    somaMais(L2,A,B,C,D)),
listaEcos(R,A,B,C,D).

somaMais([],A,B,C,D).
somaMais([L3|R3],A,B,C,D):-
nth0(1, L3, ElemType),
nth0(3, L3, ElemPerc),
( ElemPerc >= 90 ->
    (ElemType = 'Organico'
        -> soma(A,ElemPerc,F);
            (ElemType = 'Papel'
                -> soma(B,ElemPerc,G);
                    (ElemType = 'Metal'
                        -> soma(C,ElemPerc,H);
                        soma(D,ElemPerc,I),
                    )
            )
    )
somaMais(R3,F,G,H,I)).


soma(A,Elem, H):-
H is A+Elem.
```

SWI-Prolog tells me that there is a `Syntax error: Operator priority clash` on the line that corresponds to `soma(D,ElemPerc,I),`, what am I missing? Is it something wrong on all those ifs?

I have a set of garbage cans (which have a name, type, location, capacity).
The idea is that given a zone (that has several locations) I could get the sum of all the capacities over 90 from the garbage cans in that area.

So ecoZona would grab the zone and "send it" to listaEcos, this one would split the list of garbage cans (and their properties) into individual garbage cans. and then somaMais would sum the capacities (splitting paper, glass, metal and organic)

Comment: You've got an erroneous comma after `D is D1 + ElemPerc,`. Also, you're going to have trouble here because you're using `is/2` to "assign" values such as `A1 is A`. If `A` doesn't already have a value, this will be an error since `is/2` is an expression evaluator, not an assignment operator (Prolog doesn't have an assignment operator). If `A` already has a value, then `A is A1 + ElemPerc` will fail because you're trying to change `A` when it's already bound, which you cannot do inside a Prolog predicate clause.

Comment: Thanks @lurker, is there anyway I could get the values of that sums? Is there anyway i could make those sums? if i create another function that "returns" the sum value will it be okay?

Comment: Yes there's a way, and you need to take a completely different approach. You are trying to use Prolog like other languages and it doesn't work that way. You need to be more clear about what your predicate actually does. It's not clear. Perhaps show a sample query you want to make and what the expected results would be. Your new error is because you left out the comma after `)`.

Comment: Basically I have lots of recycling bins. in this part of the function I want to see if their garbage level is over 90 `ElemPerc >= 90 ->`  and if so add that level to a variable so that i could see how many cars I would need to collect all the garbage.
And I have different kinds of bins (paper, metal, organic and glass) so i need to separate those values

Comment: Prolog uses *predicates* not *functions*. A *predicate* defines a relation. Please show an example query you want to make with expected results.

Comment: What has been asked to me is that given a zone, say how many cars I would need to collect the garbage.